# What is this character ( Â ) and how do I remove it with PHP?

Tags: php, string, character-encoding

It's a capital A with a ^ on top: `Â`

It is showing up in strings pulled from webpages.  It shows up where there was previously an empty space in the original string on the original site.  This is the actual character that is stored in my database. It's also what displays on my website when I echo a string that contains it.

I realize it's a character encoding problem when I originally process the webpage, but I am now stuck with these characters in my database.  I have to convert this character when it is displayed, or somewhere else in the php before outputting html that contains it.  I cannot reprocess the original documents.

I have tried str_replace() and html_entity_decode() and neither do anything.

What else should I try?

Comment: you should not remove them by str_replace, you should fix the encoding problem first.   take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+encoding  and this http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+encoding

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"Latin 1" is your problem here. There are approx 65256 UTF-8 characters available to a web page which you cannot store in a Latin-1 code page.

For your immediate problem you should be able to

```
$clean = str_replace(chr(194)," ",$dirty)
```

However I would switch your database to use utf-8 ASAP as the problem will almost certainly reoccur.

Comment: The Unicode codespace goes up to U+10FFFF, so that's about a million code points, give or take a few illegal ones.

Comment: here's a useful chart to reference characters like this: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: @Ignacio -- very true -- I was limiting myself to the UTF-16 character set. :-}

Comment: UTF-16 has the same number of characters. You probably meant UCS-2.

Comment: Thanks for this trick, in case if someone will search for the solution how to pint out Latin-1 text from SQL Server to wordpress 
Here is str_replace(chr(194)," ",mb_convert_encoding($val, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1'));

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

```
$string = "Sentence Ã¢â‚¬Ëœnot-criticalÃ¢â‚¬â„¢ and \n sorting Ã¢â‚¬Ëœnot-criticalÃ¢â‚¬â„¢ or this \r and some Ã¢â‚¬Ëœnot-criticalÃ¢â‚¬â„¢ more. ' ! -.";
$output = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)\x0A\x0D]*/','', $string);
```

Comment: Some whitespaces are missing from my text now, but encoded chars are gone.

Comment: This was the only answer that got rid of the Â char for me.

Answer (score 8):

It isn't really one character, and is likely caused by misalignment between content encoding and browser's encoding.  Try to set the encoding of your outputted page to what you are using.

e.g. In the  section, output:

```
echo "<META http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>";
```

(Adjust UTF-8 to whatever you are using)

Comment: +1 - this is a problem that needs fixing the root cause (although merely changing headers might not entirely cut it, depending on the situation)

Comment: This is the actual character that is stored in my database. Does that change the situation at all?  My database encoding is Latin 1 (default). I'm not very familiar with encoding issues.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I didn't read the question carefully.  In that case, after you pull data from another site you need to detect its encoding and convert it to your database's encoding before storing them.  Usually it's done by parsing header like the one I gave, but depending on the site you crawl it can get complicated.

Comment: That sounds like the correct solution to the problem.  I will make that change when I get back into that part of the project.  Any suggestions for temporary solutions using PHP before outputting the character, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 3):

I use this one a lot

```
function cleanStr($value){
    $value = str_replace('Â', '', $value);
    $value = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $value);
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: That makes Â£ to lb

Answer (score 1):

This is coming from database so the best option will be remove from database using a SQL query like:

```sql
UPDATE products SET description = REPLACE(description, 'Â', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bellow codes

```
echo "<META http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($your_string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when using different charset in your web.

To solve this (using utf-8 in the examples):

in the `<HEAD>` of your page add `charset`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

In any form you submit add `accept-charset`:

```
<form name="..." method=".." id=".."  accept-charset="utf-8">
```

If you are using php+MySQLi to process your form, you should make sure the database connection is also supporting your charset. Procedural style:

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

and object oriented style:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I Actually had to have all of this:

```
    <--!DOCTYPE html--> 
    <--html lang="en-US"-->
    <--head-->
    <--meta charset="utf-8"-->   
    <--meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"--> 
    <--meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"--> 
    <--meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8/" /-->
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove â character from string

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

$price = "â‚¹ 250.00";

$price2 = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $price);
```

Result : 250.00